# Apache doesn't serve files to be interpreted by the browser but to be downloaded

Tags: apache2

I recently reinstalled my whole webserver, and I am now hosting some documents from home for personal use. Now, whenever I go to that page, it automatically downloads the .html and .php documents. I've tried Googling my problems, and no results.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your infrastructure especially the web server you are using and the relevant configuration file for the enabled site? Usually configuration files located at `/etc/your_webserver` directory.

Comment: I am using Apache2 with MySQL, and PHP5. Mod_rewrite is on, and the directory the webserver documents are at are in /var/www/filesarehere.
What else is to be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Apache does not know what to do with the related files (.php i assume) and offers them for download instead of display.

You can check if the following line exists in your site configuration file:

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Usually site configurations are stored at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and the enabled configurations (those who actually served by the server) are stored at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

The rest configuration files, such as `apache.conf` and `ports.conf:` are stored at `/etc/apache2/` directory.

Also the php module must be loaded. There must something like the following in Apache config file:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script php 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

If the above settings are missing, you need to add them yourself and issue:

`sudo service apache restart`.

For more detailed instructions you can read the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/httpd.html) chapter from the official Ubuntu documentation.

Comment: My site configuration has nothing of that sort. Same with the Apache config file.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Which file is the configuration file? Sorry, I am fairly new at these types of things.

Comment: I added it into apache2.conf in /etc/apache2, and  I get:
Syntax error on line 239 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load /etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install php5` and then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: My terminal says php5 is already installed.

Comment: Try to remove your php installation:`aptitude search php5` to look for all related packages and `sudo apt-get purge php5` to remove them. Finally `sudo apt-get install php5`.

Comment: No more errors, but it is still downloading the .php document.

Comment: Also, now I am getting: [Sun Aug 18 19:04:39 2013] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping

Comment: The reinstallation must have put a duplicate setting to load php module. You can open the configuration file and delete the duplicate. As for the original problem please check my answer.

Comment: I redid what was written in your answer. I still am encountering this again

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem:

```
apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Apache should restart automatically after that. If not, do this:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: And `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0` for php 7.0.